# What is this system icon (looks like upside down Signal strength)?

Tags: notification-bar, system-info

Does anyone know what the left-most status icon is here? The one that looks like an upside down signal status.

It only shows up randomly from time to time, and I've tried toggling on/off different settings (such as night light) to try to make it go away, but nothing has been successful.

Rebooting my phone gets rid of it, until the next time it randomly shows up in a few days or weeks.

Moto G Power running Android 10, with all current updates.

[image]

Comment: [Device user manual](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/472154.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiMxuGYuMrqAhW1zDgGHX6NC_AQFjABegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw30Se83c_HrCJ9GExgMQ6vN) **does not** mention this. Are you using a VPN?

Comment: Also check in safe mode. If it is not present in safe mode, it is because of some app.

Comment: Since this is in the system area of the notification bar, I suspect that it might be a network signal indicator of some sort - perhaps roaming or mobile hotspot?  Can you toggle "mobile data" off and see if the icon still persists?

Comment: @beeshyams no VPN.

Comment: @CzarMatt I don't use it as a mobile hot spot at all, and never really go into roaming areas. Can definitely try toggling mobile data and see what happens, though... I have to wait till it comes back.  ... One of "those" issues. lol

Comment: This issue is specific to Android 10. On a thread this issue was solved after updating to Android 11. Really curious what it is for tho

Comment: @Aayush do you happen to have a link to that thread? Would be curious to read it.

Comment: @eidylon Locked.. https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/60105843?hl=en

Comment: @CzarMatt - well, it was't mobile data. However, toggling my wifi off and back on again made it go away. 

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing it when running Blockada ad-blocker VPN. Turning it off removes the icon. If I pull down the notification bar, it changes to the normal key icon until released. Only started seeing it in the last week so maybe Blockada is tapping into this icon with a recent update.

Comment: Yeah, it's something relatively new for me too, shortly before I'd asked this question, guess as a result of a recent system update or something. I generally don't run any VPN on my phone, though could be something else using some sort of BTS networking. 

Answer (score 0):

It took me a bit of digging to figure out. It's actually a kind of rare icon. It means: 'Network/SIM/carrier-locked without prejudice'.

Say, if you have a CDMA, GSM, LTE/Dual SIM and want to use a compatible service provider SIM, you may, however, until you satisfy contractual criteria, your phone may not be officially network unlocked. This allows you to use the device, but it will look sketchy if you try to sell it. You almost never see this on postpaid phones, as when the phone is paid in full, the unlock is granted upon request, and if payment is not made, the phone is almost certainly blacklisted. You can make a NAND and edit the script to swap the IMEI with that of a broken phone, recompile the script and flash the edited firmware, or there's a simple technique to having it removed from the blacklist. Also, this icon will usually stop appearing the moment you begin using a valid SIM, and almost always makes its first appearance upon the denial of user request for network unlock.

I've noticed that on many devices, when Network unlock fails on prepaid devices, an alternative provider SIM almost always works, and sometimes, setting the phone up doing a formal soft reset and clearing any FRP issues will allow the device to be unlocked with the Network/SIM unlock app. In other words, enabling OEM unlock, (a prerequisite to unlocking the bootloader in many cases) and then doing a hard reset and curiously clicking the unlock app and seeing, "SIM unlock failed" will almost certainly trigger the presence of the NLWOP. Oh, in case anybody ever wondered what NLWOP stands for it's: Network Locked W/o Prejudice.

All in all, it's an icon that basically means no matter what SIM you use, it will still have Verizon apps that can't be uninstalled without root, and a Verizon splash screen. As long as that icon is up there, it's a dead indicator that not all the Ts were crossed and Is dotted. Except nobody knows what the hell it means, nor cares.

It's never given me any trouble other than what I've mentioned. But I've worked around that all too. By gaining root access, and learning about ADB, ADP, and with programs like Android Kitchen, which makes coding Android easy, you can make your Boost mobile phone appear to be a white box, remove all the bloatware, in some cases, flash a ROM which uses the same network from a similar device, a custom ROM, or like a ported out, streamlined Motorola ROM for your old LG, for example. The icon is only annoying and will correct itself. If you want it gone for good, the right way, just perform a web search for (your device) Network unlock eligibility criteria. Cheers.

Oh, and I had an afterthought: the icon doesn't just appear, it actually transposes your WiFi signal icon. The reason it is done this way is because there used to be great difficulty in blacklisted phones being set to WiFi only, so the WiFi signal is transposed with the 'anti-service' icon. You don't have to reset your device or anything, simply tap the Wi-Fi tile to disable WiFi, then again to enable WiFi and that will fix it every time. The evidence that this icon is the NLWOP icon, is that, more responsibly, when you drop down your notifications window, the 'anti-service' logo is now a padlock, the official Network unlock application icon.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange, a Q&A site for Android end-users and power-users! This looks like a great explanation about this matter. I did some cosmetic editing by adding some paragraphs because it was kind of difficult to read without spacing, but feel free to [edit] further to improve it, especially if the sentences grouping is not as intended. Thanks!

Comment: Also, by "ADP", did you mean "[Android Dev Phone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Dev_Phone)"?